# future tense (which sentence is correct?)

Tags: present-perfect, future-tense, present-continuous, present-simple, future-continuous

If the examinations are coming, I want to tell my mother that I will work hard before the examinations. Which sentence is correct?

A) I will work hard in next two weeks.

B) I will be working hard in next two weeks.

C) I will have been working hard in next two weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, they are all incorrect. It should be

> in **the** next two weeks.

Now on to your actual question about tenses.

C) is incorrect. It uses future perfect tense, which is usually used in a context like this

> By January, I will have lived here for 3 years.

You could say something like

> When the test date comes, I will have studied hard for two weeks.

A) and B) are both correct, and they mean basically the same thing. Here's a link that explains the difference better than I could: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28234/will-be-doing-vs-will-do